# divide error: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI

Tags: manjaro, segmentation-fault

In the past 3 days, my desktop system keeps crashing multiple times per day. It completely freezes and is unresponsive, but all of the apps still run (I can hear music/video playing correctly).

I can still `ssh` to it from my laptop, running `sudo dmesg` yields the following:

```
[ 9220.434268] divide error: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[ 9220.434276] CPU: 9 PID: 751 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.4.97-1-MANJARO #1
[ 9220.434279] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME B350-PLUS, BIOS 4022 08/08/2018
[ 9220.434425] RIP: 0010:CalculateVMAndRowBytes.constprop.0+0x212/0x910 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.434430] Code: 00 00 00 84 c0 0f 84 5b 04 00 00 45 89 e0 45 31 f6 b9 00 01 00 00 89 c8 31 d2 48 8b b4 24 c8 00 00 00 f2 0f 10 2d c6 90 20 00 <f7> 74 24 78 f2 0f 11 2c 24 31 d2 41 f7 f0 89 06 45 84 c9 74 8b 41
[ 9220.434433] RSP: 0018:ffffbf4301a9f1d0 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 9220.434436] RAX: 0000000000010000 RBX: 000000000000001f RCX: 0000000000010000
[ 9220.434439] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa2b61d9079b8 RDI: ffffbf4301a9f3bc
[ 9220.434441] RBP: 0000000000000008 R08: 0000000000000080 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 9220.434443] R10: ffffa2b61d9079b8 R11: ffffa2b61d907f28 R12: 0000000000000008
[ 9220.434445] R13: ffffa2b61d901f38 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffa2b61d901f38
[ 9220.434448] FS:  00007f32000a2940(0000) GS:ffffa2b796e40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 9220.434450] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 9220.434452] CR2: 000056271e4ae000 CR3: 000000020e188000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
[ 9220.434454] Call Trace:
[ 9220.434467]  ? preempt_schedule_irq+0x55/0x60
[ 9220.434607]  dml20v2_DISPCLKDPPCLKDCFCLKDeepSleepPrefetchParametersWatermarksAndPerformanceCalculation+0x230a/0x49d0 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.434749]  ? CalculatePrefetchSchedule.constprop.0+0xd98/0xf00 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.434887]  ? fetch_pipe_params+0x752/0xa00 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435027]  get_wm_urgent+0xe/0x20 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435156]  dml20v2_rq_dlg_get_dlg_reg+0x94/0x2640 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435240]  ? dml20v2_DISPCLKDPPCLKDCFCLKDeepSleepPrefetchParametersWatermarksAndPerformanceCalculation+0x2d5c/0x49d0 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435324]  ? CalculateFlipSchedule+0x4b1/0x530 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435408]  ? dml20v2_DISPCLKDPPCLKDCFCLKDeepSleepPrefetchParametersWatermarksAndPerformanceCalculation+0x340d/0x49d0 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435491]  ? dml20v2_DISPCLKDPPCLKDCFCLKDeepSleepPrefetchParametersWatermarksAndPerformanceCalculation+0x431b/0x49d0 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435581]  ? dcn20_calculate_dlg_params+0x3d4/0x520 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435670]  dcn20_calculate_dlg_params+0x3d4/0x520 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435759]  dcn20_validate_bandwidth_internal+0x1b2/0x2a0 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435847]  dcn20_validate_bandwidth+0x29/0xd0 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.435930]  dc_commit_updates_for_stream+0xa47/0x1580 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.436019]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0xc85/0x1f50 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.436036]  commit_tail+0x94/0x110 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 9220.436045]  drm_atomic_helper_commit+0x108/0x110 [drm_kms_helper]
[ 9220.436062]  drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x124/0x2c0 [drm]
[ 9220.436078]  ? drm_mode_obj_find_prop_id+0x40/0x40 [drm]
[ 9220.436090]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xb2/0x100 [drm]
[ 9220.436103]  drm_ioctl+0x208/0x360 [drm]
[ 9220.436118]  ? drm_mode_obj_find_prop_id+0x40/0x40 [drm]
[ 9220.436180]  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x49/0x80 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.436183]  do_vfs_ioctl+0x3eb/0x6c0
[ 9220.436187]  ksys_ioctl+0x5e/0x90
[ 9220.436189]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x16/0x20
[ 9220.436192]  do_syscall_64+0x49/0x90
[ 9220.436194]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[ 9220.436196] RIP: 0033:0x7f3200a8bf6b
[ 9220.436198] Code: ff ff ff 85 c0 79 8b 49 c7 c4 ff ff ff ff 5b 5d 4c 89 e0 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d d5 ae 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[ 9220.436199] RSP: 002b:00007fff2fe88508 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[ 9220.436201] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fff2fe88540 RCX: 00007f3200a8bf6b
[ 9220.436202] RDX: 00007fff2fe88540 RSI: 00000000c01864ba RDI: 000000000000000d
[ 9220.436203] RBP: 00000000c01864ba R08: 0000000000000068 R09: 00000000cccccccc
[ 9220.436204] R10: 0000000000000fff R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055b216868050
[ 9220.436205] R13: 000000000000000d R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000003
[ 9220.436208] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl btbcm videobuf2_common btintel bluetooth videodev mousedev input_leds ecdh_generic joydev ecc snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib snd_rawmidi snd_seq_device mc squashfs loop iwlmvm eeepc_wmi asus_wmi mac80211 battery snd_hda_codec_realtek sparse_keymap wmi_bmof snd_hda_codec_generic edac_mce_amd nls_iso8859_1 libarc4 nls_cp437 ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm_amd vfat snd_hda_intel iwlwifi fat kvm snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel cfg80211 snd_hwdep ccp snd_pcm aesni_intel r8169 snd_timer snd crypto_simd realtek sp5100_tco cryptd glue_helper libphy rfkill i2c_piix4 pcspkr k10temp soundcore rng_core wmi gpio_amdpt pinctrl_amd evdev mac_hid acpi_cpufreq uinput wacom crypto_user fuse ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 hid_generic usbhid hid sd_mod ahci
[ 9220.436240]  libahci libata crc32c_intel xhci_pci scsi_mod xhci_hcd amdgpu gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm agpgart
[ 9220.436252] ---[ end trace 0b57018bd9a96e66 ]---
[ 9220.436322] RIP: 0010:CalculateVMAndRowBytes.constprop.0+0x212/0x910 [amdgpu]
[ 9220.436324] Code: 00 00 00 84 c0 0f 84 5b 04 00 00 45 89 e0 45 31 f6 b9 00 01 00 00 89 c8 31 d2 48 8b b4 24 c8 00 00 00 f2 0f 10 2d c6 90 20 00 <f7> 74 24 78 f2 0f 11 2c 24 31 d2 41 f7 f0 89 06 45 84 c9 74 8b 41
[ 9220.436325] RSP: 0018:ffffbf4301a9f1d0 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 9220.436327] RAX: 0000000000010000 RBX: 000000000000001f RCX: 0000000000010000
[ 9220.436328] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffa2b61d9079b8 RDI: ffffbf4301a9f3bc
[ 9220.436329] RBP: 0000000000000008 R08: 0000000000000080 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 9220.436330] R10: ffffa2b61d9079b8 R11: ffffa2b61d907f28 R12: 0000000000000008
[ 9220.436330] R13: ffffa2b61d901f38 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffa2b61d901f38
[ 9220.436332] FS:  00007f32000a2940(0000) GS:ffffa2b796e40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 9220.436333] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 9220.436334] CR2: 000056271e4ae000 CR3: 000000020e188000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
```

The stack trace indicates that it might have something to do with the driver for my GPU.

The parameters of my system (running `inxi -Fazi`) are as follows:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.97-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4-x86_64 root=UUID=ebeffc9d-5ca3-447e-8161-9feaf3fa0498 rw quiet 
           udev.log_priority=3 resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/ebeffc9d-5ca3-447e-8161-9feaf3fa0498 resume_offset=34816 
           Desktop: i3 4.19.1 info: i3bar dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20KGS99C00 v: ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20KGS99C00 v: SDK0J40697 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: N23ET56W (1.31 ) 
           date: 09/17/2018 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 50.5 Wh condition: 50.6/57.0 Wh (89%) volts: 12.9/11.6 model: LGC 01AV494 type: Li-poly 
           serial: <filter> status: Unknown cycles: 76 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-8550U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake note: check family: 6 
           model-id: 8E (142) stepping: A (10) microcode: E0 L2 cache: 8 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 32012 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/4000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 801 3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: Split huge pages 
           Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable 
           Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
           Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
           Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
           Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:5917 
           class ID: 0300 
           Device-2: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus ID: 1-8:6 chip ID: 5986:2115 class ID: 0e02 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.10 driver: loaded: intel unloaded: modesetting alternate: fbdev,vesa display ID: :0 
           screens: 1 
           Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 508x285mm (20.0x11.2") s-diag: 582mm (22.9") 
           Monitor-1: eDP1 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 157 size: 310x170mm (12.2x6.7") diag: 354mm (13.9") 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.4 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_soc_skl 
           bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:9d71 class ID: 0403 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.97-1-MANJARO 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V vendor: Lenovo driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: efa0 bus ID: 00:1f.6 
           chip ID: 8086:15d8 class ID: 0200 
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: efa0 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 8086:24fd 
           class ID: 0280 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IP v4: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global broadcast: <filter> 
           IP v6: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global 
           IP v6: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global 
           IP v6: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: link 
           WAN IP: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus ID: 1-7:5 chip ID: 8087:0a2b 
           class ID: e001 
           Message: Required tool hciconfig not installed. Check --recommends 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 146.07 GiB (61.3%) 
           SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKKF256G8L size: 238.47 GiB block size: physical: 512 B 
           logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 rotation: SSD serial: <filter> rev: L14P scheme: MBR 
Partition: ID-1: / raw size: 237.97 GiB size: 233.24 GiB (98.01%) used: 146.07 GiB (62.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
           maj-min: 259:2 
Swap:      Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache pressure: 100 (default) 
           ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 15.18 GiB used: 214.8 MiB (1.4%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Info:      Processes: 220 Uptime: 2d 4h 00m wakeups: 62229 Memory: 15.18 GiB used: 3.52 GiB (23.2%) Init: systemd v: 247 
           Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: pacman: 1515 lib: 367 Shell: fish v: 3.1.2 running in: mate-terminal inxi: 3.3.01
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm seeing the same on Archlinux. Probably this bug: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1418

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the system to `5.4.100` seemed to have solved the issue.